# Is it possible to play audio with HTML5 as long as it is published using PHP and JS?

Tags: javascript, php, audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming

**TLDR; Is there a way load an audio file with something like an AJAX POST Request to a PHP handler and have it load the the file to be played within the browser?**

I am trying to create a page where podcasts can be uploaded. I want to have the ability to "publish" or "unpublish." I have each podcast added get added to a database with it's information and with a publish column that can be true or false. Currently I use the following code PHP:

```
if(isPublished()){

 header('Cache-Control: max-age=100000');
          header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
          header('Content-Type: audio/'.$fileExt.''); // sets the output content type to wav
          header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($podL)); // sets the legth of the file (in order to the HTML5 player to access the audio duration)
          header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
          header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$podID.".".$fileExt.'"'); // set an output file name

          readfile($podL); // reads the file
}
```

And the HTML audio controls link to the php play audio page:

```
<audio controls>
<!--$podL is just the ID and $podE is the file extension-->
    <source src="<?php echo "playAudio.php?link=".$podL; ?>" type="audio/<?php echo $podE; ?>">
</audio>
```

*The podcasts are store in a podcast folder and I've used htaccess Deny All so that files can't be accessed directly.*

This works great for small audio files, however podcasts can be hours long which is where the issue comes in. The script execution is probably timing out, but basically after 10 or so minutes the audio stops. I don't want to raise execution timers as while this goes it basically prevents a new page load until you pause and let the buffer finish.

If the content is published, I don't care if someone can download it. I just want to give the author the ability to pause publication or take down a publication without having to delete the whole thing.

This is what I have done for articles, but they exist in the database entirely. I suspect I could do something similar but just can't find any solution (method) online. With readfile() I don't have to worry about memory.

```
$.post("read.inc.php", {
    aid: aid
  }, function(data, status){
    if (data.includes("error: not published")) {
      $("#title").append("<p>Article is Unavailable/Not Published</p>");
    } else {

      const explData = data.split("|");
      const title = explData['0'];
      const author = explData['1'];
      const datetime = explData['2'];
      const postTime = new Date(datetime*1000);
      const stringStuff = explData['3'];
      $("#title").append("<p>"+title+"</p>");
      $("#author").append("Author: "+author);
      $("#postTime").append("Published: "+postTime);
      const deltaStuff = JSON.parse(stringStuff);
      quill.setContents(deltaStuff);
    }
  });
```

**If there are other languages or libraries better suited in a web environment, I am open to it.**